# How to blinking effect on the one button, when clicked on other buttons....?

Tags: android, button, listener, sleep, wait

I have some buttons one is main, others are child, I want blinking effect on main button when I touch child buttons.

I have used onTouchListener on all child buttons, in those listeners, I am calling a method which i used to blink the main button.

method.

```
   public void refreshMainButton() {
        Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.tabouterover_one));
        Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.tabouterover_two));
        Bitmap b3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.tabouterover_three));
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.tabmain_two));

        BitmapDrawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(b1);
        outerImageViews[1].setBackgroundDrawable(d1);
        BitmapDrawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable(b2);
        outerImageViews[1].setBackgroundDrawable(d2);
        BitmapDrawable d3 = new BitmapDrawable(b3);
        outerImageViews[1].setBackgroundDrawable(d3);

        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        BitmapDrawable d4 = new BitmapDrawable(b);
        outerImageViews[1].setBackgroundDrawable(d4);
    }
```

This is showing no effect on main button.

If any one has any idea, please help me.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) to archive this effect.

Android has very harsh limits in the Activity - if the Activity does not respond within a certain time (I guess it was 5 seconds) the application shows a dialog to end it. Into this trap you will run (perhaps) with the wait construct.

Now you might think of laying this out into a thread. But this won't work, because the UI can only be manipulated from inside the activity.

So just create an animation and start it. Android will do the reset :)
I hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you for you response, but which animation will be help full in changing the buttons background image..?

Comment: If I understood your problem right - then yes. Use the link in the answer and scroll down to the bottom. There is an example, that shows how to change the background. (In this case it is an ImageView but that shouldn't matter.)